# Updating a tkinter progressbar until a video is played

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6, opencv, python

I have a use case where I need to bind a ttk progressbar until a video feed is being played.

I have made a parent container which needs to hold a Videofeed, and a widget(progressbar). I am using the tk.Label.update() method for displaying my video in the container.

Also, I have a flag, which counts the number of frames being displayed. I capped it to count until 60. This flag is also used to set the variable for the progressbar.

My video is being displayed but the progressbar is not showing. Can anyone help me fix the problem ?
`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

MAX = 60

root = tk.Tk()
screen_width,screen_height = root.winfo_screenwidth(),root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(screen_width, screen_height))
progress_var = tk.DoubleVar() #here you have ints but when calc. %'s usually floats
ImageLabel = tk.Label(root, width=screen_width,height=screen_height,)
ImageLabel.pack()
progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(root, variable=progress_var, maximum=MAX)
progressbar.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=1)


def loop_function():

    k = 0
    cap=cv2.VideoCapture("myvideo.avi")
    while k <= MAX:
        val,frame=cap.read()

        if val:
            img = Image.fromarray(frame)
            imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
            ImageLabel.imgtk = imgtk
            ImageLabel.configure(image=imgtk)
            progress_var.set(k)
            k += 1
            time.sleep(1)
            root.update()
    cap.release()
    #root.after(100, loop_function)

loop_function()
root.mainloop()
```

`